# Nightmare (Unity training day) Parte do script nao encontrado

Tags: script, unity-5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Olá 
estou configurando o script do "Playermovement" do projeto Nightmare da UTD 2014, bom, chegando nessa parte (mostrado na foto) fui configurar o script para o player seguir o mouse, porem o transform nao achou o "position", segui o tutorial corretamente em todos os passos, mas nessa etapa do "PlayerToMouse" nao conseguir colocar "Transform.position",eu uso Microsoft Visual Studio (atualizado)
obs: sem falar que as vezes da erro na hora de subtrair pelo floorhit, dizendo que o "-" nao é um caractere valido. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

o seu floorHit é um Vector3? Caso nao seja voce tera q fazer da seguinte forma para diminuir em todas as posicoes: "Vector3 playerToMouse = new Vector3 (transform.position.x - floorHit, transform.position.y - floorHit, transform.position.z - floorHit)" t minusculo

Comment: Como disse, agora deu erro na hora de aplicar o ''-'' pq nao consegue aplica-lo no ''float'' e no raycasthit,tirei uma foto pra vc ver de uma coisa que tbm ocorreu, oq posso fazer? to meio perdido ;-; http://imgur.com/WEcvkoN

Comment: Tenta transforma os seu raycasthit num float se eu nao me engano vc pode fazer assim ' float x = floorHit(float)';